# Python win32com convert first row to lower case

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I wish to convert the first row of my excel file to lowercase. How do it do it:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.Visible=False
for i in files:
    doc = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath+'/'+str(i))
    ws = doc.Worksheets(str(i).split(".")[0])
    ws.Rows(1).Cells.Value=lower(ws.Rows(1).Cells.Value)  #This syntax is wrong 
    ws.Rows(1).Replace("_","")
    ws.Rows(1).Replace(" ","")
    doc.Save()
    doc.Close()
    ws.Replace()
```

Comment: Try : `ws.Rows(1).Cells.Value = ws.Rows(1).Cells.Value.lower()`

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower' @t.m.adam

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your failed may be `Cells.Value` return `((str1, str2, ... None, None, ...),)` this data type.

So try to iterate the row's cell to change value

```
for cell in sheet.Rows(1).Cells:
    pre_value = cell.Value
    if pre_value is None:
        break
    if type(pre_value) is str:
        cell.Value = pre_value.lower()
```